# How Do I Draw A Line In Elm?

Tags: tree, draw, diagram, lines, elm

This code is a tree diagram without the lines. How do I implement and draw the lines in this code?

```
main = collage 700 700 ( drawTree exampleTree (0,0) 1)

drawNode name = group 
                  [filled red <| circle 50
                  , text <|fromString name]

type Tree = Node String Tree Tree | Nil

exampleTree = Node "Me" (Node "Mother" 
                             (Node "Grandmother" Nil Nil)
                             (Node "Grandfather" Nil Nil))
                       (Node "Father"
                             (Node "Grandfather" Nil Nil)
                             (Node "Grandmother" Nil Nil))

drawTree : Tree ->(Float, Float) -> Float -> List Form
drawTree tree (x,y) depth = case tree of
                        (Node ss t1 t2 )-> move (x,y) (drawNode ss) :: (List.append (drawTree t1 (x+100+depth,y+100) (depth+50)) (drawTree t2 (x-100-depth,y+100)(depth+50)))
                        Nil -> []
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you've found `collage`; on the very same page of documentation, you should be able to find the functions for [creating a line](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Graphics-Collage#segment) and [tracing](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Graphics-Collage#traced) it...

Comment: i am confused on how to apply the documentation

Comment: Perhaps you could try writing a simpler standalone elm program that just draws a single line, then once you understand, try again with the tree? The [lines demo](http://elm-lang.org/examples/lines) should help.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but I don't know how to implement it into my code so that it displays.

Comment: Well, it looks like you're managing to create some shapes in `drawNode`; maybe start by adding some lines there?